# How do I find out if a user has cookies disabled in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, cookies

I need to display a message if the user has cookies disabled. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/531393/how-to-detect-if-cookies-are-disabled-is-it-possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the `Request.Cookies` property which would return an empty `HttpCookieCollection`.

In Javascript, the usual way to check is the Navigator.cookieEnabled property (works on IE, for other browsers, I think you need to set a cookie and try to read back its value).

Answer (score 1):

Save some test value and try to re-read it at the next request.

But honestly, your approach is not user friendly. There is hardly any technical reason to deny a service with cookies disabled. You can fall gracefully and just store the values in session.

Anyway, if a user has "In-private" browsing mode on (now available in both IE & FF meaning almost all users) your cookies will anyway be gone after the user's done and there is no way you can detect the "in-private" mode.

Comment: I agree with the graceful degrade philosophy... +1

Comment: Unfortunately this is a business requirement. I'm a bit too lowly to question those. :)

Comment: @User: well, I was using `Session_Start(){...}` to check `Request.AcceptedLanguages` and set

Answer (score 0):

The only way is to store a value in cookie and check if you get the value back.