# How do I check if the browser supports cookies, in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iphone, session, cookies

Especially for the iPhone

Comment: If you are interested in the iphone, use the html5 Storage object instead of cookies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works in IE, Chrome and Safari (which should be the same as iPhone):

```
if (navigator.cookieEnabled)
   alert("ON");
else
   alert("OFF");
```

**EDIT:** Since nvl decided to take my answer and not check into it I thought I should. Tested it on all the browsers I could find and seems to work just fine.

Comment: I relied on you! :P and I think you are more worried with my taking your answer (i was trying to make my answer cross-browser compliant, i checked only for Chrome and FF) than actually checking, so I delete it.

Comment: `cookieEnabled` is really unreliable. See eg. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2167310/how-to-show-a-message-only-if-cookies-are-disabled-in-browser/2167462#2167462