# how to know the browser support cookie using python or django

Tags: python, django, cookies, browser

I want to check whether the web browser supports cookies, before I set cookies. How to do it using python or django.
I didnt find it on google and python document and django doc? 
any one knows? thx

Comment: This may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/531393/how-to-detect-if-cookies-are-disabled-is-it-possible

Comment: examples with python django would be better. thx

Answer (score 2):

Check [setting test cookies](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.0/topics/http/sessions/#setting-test-cookies) to test whether the user's browser accepts cookies.

Comment: this doc is talking about sessions,right? Does it work fine for cookies? I find `set_cookie` in [Request and response objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpResponse.set_cookie) @Aamir Adnan

Comment: But how to check the support information for COOKIES? @Aamir Adnan

Comment: @NickDong your question makes no sense. The answer quite clearly refers to setting test *cookies* to check *cookie* support. The fact that it's implemented as part of the sessions framework is completely irrelevant.

Comment: Please read the doc, it is defined there that you need to set the test cookie first using `set_test_cookie() ` and then in other view check if it is worked using `test_cookie_worked()`. Unfortunately two requests are involved in this process. There is no direct way of checking this.

Comment: @Aamir Adnan  I still confused about it call two functions in a same view call in [setting-test-cookies](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.0/topics/http/sessions/#setting-test-cookies)

Comment: It's conflict with ` then in other view check if it is worked`.

Comment: @NickDong what i mean is that there are two requests involved in the process. You can redirect to the same view where you set the cookie to further test if it is worked. have you looked into the `login` example mentioned in the link i mention?

Comment: So basically there's no useful way of doing it; just try to set the cookie and hope it works.