# Multiple sessionIDs created for one user - how can this be?

Tags: php, session, firefox

One (and only one) of my end users has some issues with being logged out.  I discovered that there are multiple PHP SessionID's being created, and that the older sessionIDs are timing out causing the logout.

The problem is the multiple session IDs.  I cannot reproduce how this is happening.  They are using Firefox, as am I.  I've tried opening new windows by double-clicking the desktop icon, going to `File -> Open New Window`, and right-clicking a link in the app and choosing `Open Link in New Window`.   Everything I do opens a new window with the same SessionID (on my system).  This is expected behaviour.

Is there another way this user could be opening windows that might create a separate SessionID?   I don't have access to their system, only logging data from my application.

Comment: check for output/whitespace before session_start() in your code.

Comment: They might have cookies disabled, so it would prevent them from keeping the session.

Comment: @John -- Only one user experiences this problem.  It is not happening for me.  If there were whitespace, the problem would happen for all users.

Comment: @J-- is there a programmatic way to determine whether cookies are disabled?

Comment: `(session_id())` would work ?

Comment: @acoder check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6663859/check-if-cookies-are-enabled

Comment: If they had cookies disabled, they wouldn't have logout issues. They would've had login issues.

Comment: detect if cookies are disabled : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/531393/how-to-detect-if-cookies-are-disabled-is-it-possible

Comment: How about subdomains? Maybe the cookies are registered under different domains, but read on all of them. (Like `.domain.com`.) Does your site allow subdomains?

Comment: No - just a single domain.

Comment: I misread. If the user is logged in and out immediately and the server registers new sessions, that's probably cookie security (like disabled).

Comment: Negative -- they are logged in and remain so until the first created session reaches maturity.  The system then does what it is supposed to do, which is log them out.  Ordinarily, they would have one session for however many tabs/windows.  That is what is happening with every user except the one.

Comment: http://www.fusioncube.net/index.php/multiple-sessions-firefox

Comment: Have you asked about browser he uses? And has he tried another one?

Comment: @Jari -- she and all users only use Firefox (system requirement - we do not support `Internet Exploder`).   I have log data to confim that only firefox is being utilized.

Answer (score 0):

He is most likely using a different firefox browsers.

You can use [PHP mobile detect](https://github.com/serbanghita/Mobile-Detect) to give you all the information on the browser

i think it will confirm my guess.

There are multiple variants of firefox and most ofthen they send the same headers so you will not know if they are using 2 differnet ones:

1. [firefox](http://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/new/)(the original)
2. [Tor project](https://www.torproject.org/download/download)
3. [Comodo Ice Dragon](http://www.comodo.com/home/browsers-toolbars/icedragon-browser.php)
4. [portable Firefox](http://portableapps.com/apps/internet/firefox_portable)
5. ...

I cannot think of a way where the same Session_ID cookie would have the same value for the same domain.

Maybe some obscure plugin is tempering with the browser.

**FIX :**
Try changing the name of your session id [(php manual)](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-id.php)

exemple :

```
<?php

 session_name("My_new_session_id" );
 session_start();
```

It is generally asked to change the session name to a less obvious name like : "qwerty"

**EDIT :**

A quick example of a secure Session management : [link](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/how-to-create-bulletproof-sessions)

For more information : [OWasp Session Management Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Session_Management_Cheat_Sheet)

Comment: Thanks - the end user is technically immature.  I will confirm this is not happening.

Answer (score 0):

Circling back on this question.  The problem turned out to be a workflow issue with one of the users. The problem was resolved with education.