# Optionally Block Google Analytics

Tags: php, google-analytics

I want to give website visitors a chance to opt out of Google Analytics. However, the website I am working on is in PHP, so Google's Analytics seems to happen all on the server side. Visiting the webpage "inCognito, inPrivate or with private browsing" does not stop Google from accessing the general location, etc.

Is there a simple way while still keeping the page PHP rather than HTML to give the user a chance to opt-out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple example you can build on:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <?php
            if(!$blockGA)
                echo '<script type="text/javascript">

                    var _gaq = _gaq || [];';
                    // etc
        ?>
    </head>
    <body>
        Hello world!
        <?php
            // Some more PHP
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

You could store the setting in a database, store it in a `SESSION`, or simply use a persistent query string like `$_GET['blockGA']`.

Comment: Or you could set a long period (1 year) cookie

Comment: @Danny Thanks. I don't want to ever explicitly ask users, so I might simply check if [cookies are enabled](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/531393/how-to-detect-if-cookies-are-disabled-is-it-possible) and then use the above.

Comment: @JonathanAbbott Just in case you didn't already know, you can get and set cookies directly with PHP; no JS is necessary: http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php

Comment: Ended up not using cookies as inCognito, inPrivate or with private browsing seem to allow cookies during the session. Best to point users towards [Google Analytics Opt-out Add-on](https://tools.google.com/dlpage/gaoptout) or work with [DNT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Do_Not_Track) (Do Not Track)