# Redirect when cookies are disabled

Tags: javascript, cookies

I need JavaScript code that will detect if a user has cookies disabled in their browser. If they do, they will be redirected to another page. If they have their cookies enabled it just goes straight through as usual.

Comment: I need many things too...

Comment: I'd suggest a simple [>Google search<](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+to+detect+cookies+enabled&rlz=1C1TSNP_enUS471US471&oq=javascript+to+detect+cookies&aqs=chrome.1.57j0l3j62.8473j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) first.  Did you even look?

Comment: Similar thread,
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/531393/how-to-detect-if-cookies-are-disabled-is-it-possible

Comment: this is not a question but a request. you need to include what you have done so far when posting a question here.

Answer (score 1):

You can insert a test cookie in browser and call back that cookie again.

Use this library. It contan simple function to identify cookies enabled, create/read or erase cookies.

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    /* function to create cookie
    @param name of the cookie
    @param value of the cookie
    @param validity of the cookie
    */
        function createCookie(name, value, days) { 
            var expires;
            if (days) {
                var date = new Date();
                date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
                expires = "; expires=" + date.toGMTString();
            }
            else expires = "";
            document.cookie = name + "=" + value + expires + "; path=/";
        }

        function readCookie(name) {
            var nameEQ = name + "=";
            var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
            for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
                var c = ca[i];
                while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') c = c.substring(1, c.length);
                if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length, c.length);
            }
            return null;
        }

        function eraseCookie(name) {
            createCookie(name, "", -1);
        }
    /* 
       This function will create a new cookie and reading the same cookie. 
    */
        function areCookiesEnabled() {
            var r = false;
            createCookie("testing", "Hello", 1); //creating new cookie
            if (readCookie("testing") != null) { //reading previously created cookie
                r = true;
                eraseCookie("testing");
            }
            return r; //true if cookie enabled.
        }
    </script>
```

and your code must be.

```
<script>
if(!areCookiesEnabled())
{

//redirect to page
}

</script>
```

Comment: i need if cookies are disabled to redirect.

Comment: so i added a not(!) inside 'IF' condition..:)

Comment: This works but it still hits the page for a split second before redirection. Is there anyway to make it instant as i am trying to protect advertising impressions form hit bots that don't have cookies enabled

Comment: I dont think there are direct ways to check. This is the best way.