# Logic for Cookie and Javascript disable in browser in Spring controller

Tags: spring-mvc

I have created custom login form using SpringFramework3.2 and Springsecurity3.2. If in browser cookie and javascript is disable then I will redirect it to another page showing custome message. But require logic for cookie and javascript disable in Spring controller. Can anybody tell that logic. Will appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

1. your site should work without requiring javascript or cookies. Google will likely not index your site and you will get fewer visitors. Some people disable javascript or cookies, and they won't be your customers either.
2. To detect whether javascript is enabled from your server see [How to detect if JavaScript is disabled?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/121203/how-to-detect-if-javascript-is-disabled)
3. To detect whether cookies are enabled from your server see [How to detect server-side whether cookies are disabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/531393/how-to-detect-server-side-whether-cookies-are-disabled)