# How to test if browser supports cookies in a Django app?

Tags: django, facebook, cookies

I am building a django app which requires user authentication for users to surf the web site. I read through many docs and tutorials which say to use ***set_test_cookie(), test_cookie_worked() and delete_test_cookie()*** functionality to test whether client's browser supports cookie management.

However this approach requires two requests and views to verify if cookie management is supported in client's browser or not. My question is how to implement Facebook like functionality in cookie management here. Here's how FB handles cookie check -

1) If I am not logged in and I have disabled cookie support then I am not allowed to log in prompting that I must enable cookie support to access my page.

2) Suppose I was logged in before and cookie was set up but I now disable cookie support then if I access facebook.com then it logs me out in just one request and asking me log in again. But if I log in again then it is same as the first case.

3) If I am on my timeline and browsing facebook then without closing that tab if I disable cookie support in browser, I get automatically logged out prompting that cookie support should be enabled.

How does Facebook (same as gmail) know without my sending request that cookie support is disabled in the mid and I get logged out? Does it continuously make *Ajax* calls to the server? How do I implement this functionality in my django app?

Comment: Take a look at this, this is applicable to Django too http://stackoverflow.com/a/590364/4724196